# proguardRelease FAILED when compiling apk with assembleRelease in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, proguard

I'm trying to compile my app as assembleRelease in Android Studio 1.0.1 and get the following message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

The app compiles and runs perfectly in debug mode, and assembleRelease worked with Android Studio 0.8.

The `proguard-rules.pro` file is empty. The `build.gradle` file and the full error are shown below.

Anybody can help?

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        absolutePaths false
        lintConfig file("lint.xml")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'aars'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.urbanairship:urbanairship-lib:+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.1.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.3.4@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.0@jar'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.1'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.0'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
}
```

The error is

```
13:40:19: Executing external task 'assembleRelease'...
:app:preBuild
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6171Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComSothreeSlidinguppanelLibrary202Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComUrbanairshipUrbanairshipLib510Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareMeGrantlandAutofittextview011Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareNetDanlewAndroidJoda240Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareSeEmilsjolanderStickyScrollViewItems110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareSeEmilsjolanderStickylistheaders250Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
Note: <path_to_my_project>/app/src/main/java/com/xxx/xxx/fragments/MatchCenterFragment.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:compileReleaseJava
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:compileReleaseNdk
:app:proguardRelease
Warning: com.ooyala.android.player.WidevineLibPlayer: can't find superclass or interface com.widevine.drmapi.android.WVEventListener
( more com.ooyala.* warnings )
Warning: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl: can't find referenced method 'long getContentLengthLong()' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl
Warning: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl: can't find referenced method 'long getHeaderFieldLong(java.lang.String,long)' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl
Warning: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getContentLengthLong()' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpURLConnection
Warning: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getHeaderFieldLong(java.lang.String,long)' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpURLConnection
Warning: okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: there were 234 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 4 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
:app:proguardRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.674 secs
Please correct the above warnings first.
13:40:35: External task execution finished 'assembleRelease'.
```

Comment: The build output has a number of warnings about bad references, and despite the fact that it's calling them "warnings", it looks like they're fatal errors in the end.

Comment: @ScottBarta but it works in debug, so it seems to be an issue with proguard, and I do not know how to debug that.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Add this to ProGuard setting file(like proguard-rules.pro)

```
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Comment: where to put this line

Comment: @septemberboy7 put in the proguard setting file like 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: use dontwarn for every library that is causing this issue.

Correct answer - upvote

Comment: @hoi request to explain answer with some detail information. Why this statement is required and what is does?

Comment: @Chitrang I followed the description "If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.

Comment: This solved it for me, just thought I'd mention this, a year later as it is...!

Comment: The problem is the lack these types in the Android platform.

Comment: there is a file under `Gradle Scripts` that name is `proguard-rules.pro`. click on that and type `-dontwarn okio.**`

Answer (score 19):

I had to disable proguard with

```
minifyEnabled false
```

Not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: Beware using minifyEnabled false, it will disable securing your app and reducing apk size.

Comment: If you set minifyEnabled to false, proguard won't obsfucate your code ! In a common way, you have to set this to true in release mode.

Comment: if you decompile the app , all person can see your code, is not a solution is a security issue, minifyEnabled false is just for development

Comment: This will hunt your life in production

Comment: DON'T DO THIS, As everyone above said, you're not fixing the issue here, you're just avoiding it by disabling Proguard

Answer (score 9):

Add this to ProGuard setting file(like proguard-rules.pro)

```
-ignorewarnings
```

Comment: saved my day! works like charm.I had got his transformclassesandresourceswithproguardforUat error

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with Gradle 1.1.0. It remembered some old class references which I have moved, and I couldn't build apk.

Try **Build** > **Clean**.

It helped me, and now I can build apk again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already resolve your problem. Anyway see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29858070/3864698

The fix is planned for Gradle Plugin version 1.4. So we must wait a little bit.