# Android Gradle Build Failed (Release Build type)

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, proguard

I have changed the minifyEnabled to true in build.gradle file. Then i got the issue

```
 Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

**dependencies**

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
debugCompile project(path: ':djlibrary')
releaseCompile project(path: ':djlibrary')
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
```

There is some issue with proguard. Kindly help me with this to get it done

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua

Comment: @jay check this link might it will help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547757/proguardrelease-failed-when-compiling-apk-with-assemblerelease-in-android-studio]

Comment: `Please correct the above warnings first.` what does your warnings tell you?

Comment: please add full warning lines above

Comment: @Shyam it worked when i add -dontwarn in proguard

Comment: Which library was that?

Comment: `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'`, is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

When using **Firebase Authentication** with `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'` try adding the following flags to your proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Read more at [Set up Firebase Authentication for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/).

For **Firebase Realtime Database** with `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'` you need to consider how your model objects will be serialized and deserialized after obfuscation. For details, read more at [Set up Firebase Realtime Database for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/).