# Android Studio 3.2.1 - How to Ignore Warning during Build

Tags: android, android-studio, lint, suppress-warnings

I just updated Android Studio version from 3.0.1 to 3.2.1 and started getting warning during build to ignore them I mentioned lintOptions within android tag inside app level build.gradle

```
 lintOptions {
     abortOnError false
 }
```

So how can I ignore them to run my app as I was able to run earlier

Please see attached Screenshot for more clarity

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: try deleting build folder

Comment: @Redman tried still unable to run showing warning only

Comment: Are you using any database ? If so then uninstall app from device and install again

Comment: yes I uninstalled app from TV and tried again but warnings won't allow me to test it on TV as getting at the time of build

Comment: click on /ab button on leftside and post the error which you are getting

Comment: I had same problem, but amazingly below answer worked for me
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28336720/1441476